# Show search results on another view with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm working with CakePHP now and I need to do a search with one view and then send the data to another action on the same controller, that will trigger another view with the results of that search. The thing is, on the search screen, there's also a table showing some data of the same model, and I believe that's one big problem.
So right now, it's here what I got:

```
public function busca() {
    $emergency = TableRegistry::get('EmergencySheets');
    $manufacturers = TableRegistry::get('Manufacturers');
    $data = $this->request->is('get') ? $this->request->query : $this->request->getData();
    $query = $emergency->find()
    ->select(['id', 'data_atualizacao_fabricante', 'tarja', 'manufacturer_id', 'nome_comercial'])
    ->where('EmergencySheets.data_atualizacao_fabricante')
    ->order(['data_atualizacao_fabricante'=>'DESC'])
    ->limit(7);
    $manufacturer_query = $manufacturers->find()
    ->select(['id','nome'])
    ->where($query->manufacturer_id = 'id');
    $manufacturer = $manufacturer_query->toArray();
    $sheets = $query->toArray();
    $this->set('manufacturers', $manufacturer);
    $this->set('sheets', $sheets);
    if($data){
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'ficha' , $data]);
    }else{
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'busca404']);
    }
}
```

How can I handle this?
Thank you all!

Edit:
Forgot to mention, but the $data variable always come empty on the form, even when I type something on the form input. Here's the view code, too!

```
<section class="search-section">
<div class="container px-0">
    <div class="search-wrapper">
        <div class="search-title">
            <h2><span>Quais produtos</span>você vai transportar?</h2>
            <p><span>Pesquise pelos produtos no campo de busca</span>
                ou clique nas letras ao lado.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="search-bar">
            <?=$this->Form->create()?>
                <div class="ml-5 bar">                        
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Procure várias fichas de uma só vez" class="formcontrol tip"
                            data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">
                        <span class="removeClick"><i class="fas fa-times-circle fa-2x"></i></span>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-search fa-2x"></i></button>                        
                </div>
            <?=$this->Form->end()?>
            <div class="ml-5 alfabeto text-center">
                <button href="#A">A</button> <button href="#B">B</button> <button href="#C">C</button> <button href="#D">D</button>
                <button href="#E">E</button> <button href="#F">F</button> <button href="#G">G</button> <button href="#H">H</button>
                <button href="#I">I</button> <button href="#J">J</button> <button href="#K">K</button> <button href="#L">L</button>
                <button href="#M">M</button> <button href="#N">N</button> <button href="#O">O</button> <button href="#P">P</button>
                <button href="#Q">Q</button> <button href="#R">R</button> <button href="#S">S</button> <button href="#T">T</button>
                <button href="#U">U</button> <button href="#V">V</button> <button href="#W">W</button> <button href="#X">X</button>
                <button href="#Y">Y</button> <button href="#Z">Z</button><button href="#0-9">0-9</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are various ways of doing this. Which one is best depends on various things. Do you want the search form to still be visible on the results page, e.g. for refinements or new searches? Do you want the results page to be something people can bookmark?

Comment: Hi!
The result screen that I have now, got another input to search for new stuff, so there's no need to keep the search form visible.
The flow gonna be something like:
User get to the search screen>input data>data is transfered as params to the results, on the second screen>results got shown>if user has another search, the screen has a input, so the same action is called, recursively.
Hope I don't screwed explaning it . xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the same function and template for the search form and results. Eliminate the whole `if` section with redirects, only do the search if there is data to search on, and change your view to check whether there are results to display. Something like this:

```
$data = $this->request->is('get') ? $this->request->getQueryParams() : $this->request->getData();
if (!empty($data)) {
    // Do your searches using $data here, set the results for the view
    $this->set('results', $results);
}
```

Then in your template, you have it like you've shown, but add a section with

```
if (isset($results)):
    // Display your search results here
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider that you are puting code after the line:

```
return $this->redirect(['action' => 'busca404']);
}
```

In that case all those lines wont be executed in any case because you are forcing redirects either if the request is "get" or not. So all that code wont be executed.

I think that you need to define the conditions to redirect to the "ficha" action and in which conditions remain in to the "busca" action

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the advice, didn't even realize the mistake! As for the conditions, I don't really know what to do, as the $data variable always come empty.